# Why is this python indentation not throwing an error?

Tags: python, coding-style, indentation, pep8, pep

We recently found a bug in our python script and was fixed (tested, committed and pushed) by a colleague on someone else's system. At the time, nothing seemed off. However, when I fired up the script in my emacs, I noticed that the indentation was not correct. Here are the offending lines:

```
$ cat -T -E poc.py | grep -nC 3 -F 'up_con not in check'
448-                        up_cons = [up_con[0].encode('utf-8') for up_con in up_cons if up_con and up_con[0]]$
449-^I^I    logger.debug("Got parent concepts %s", up_cons)$
450-                    for up_con in up_cons:$
451:^I^I^Iif up_con != con and up_con not in check_cons:$
452-                            check_cons.append(up_con)$
453-                        idx_con_map[i][up_con] = 1$
454-$
```

> Those who're unaware, `^I` implies a hard-tab, and `$` implies the
>   end-of-line.

Running tests on this script resulted in correct output at the time. When I noticed the mixup in the indentation levels, I naturally thought that those tests were somehow wrong. However, fixing the indentations back to 4-spaces rule:

```
$ cat -T -E poc.py | grep -nC 3 -F 'up_con not in check'
448-                        up_cons = [up_con[0].encode('utf-8') for up_con in up_cons if up_con and up_con[0]]$
449-                    logger.debug("Got parent concepts %s", up_cons)$
450-                    for up_con in up_cons:$
451:                        if up_con != con and up_con not in check_cons:$
452-                            check_cons.append(up_con)$
453-                        idx_con_map[i][up_con] = 1$
454-$
```

resulted in the same execution. No errors were thrown previously, no changes in program execution was observed this time.

My question is, why? Shouldn't python cry out that there were different levels of indentation etc.?

Here are the levels of indentation each line is at:

```
Line - with 4-spaces - with tabs
448  -     6         -      6
449  -     5         -      3 <- should cause an error
450  -     5         -      5
451  -     6         -      3 <- shouldn't produce correct outputs
452  -     7         -      7
453  -     6         -      6
```

Comment: I'm not sure how to check this but are the tabs interpreting as 8 spaces instead of 4?

Comment: @Frito Wouldn't that change from system to system? Or is there such a commandline argument for python shell as well?

Comment: I'm not sure if it's system to system or python versions. If I recall correctly older version of python treated tabs as 8 spaces. That's one of the reasons PEP8 suggests using 4 spaces and not using tabs at all. I know you can run your apps as `python -tt /path/to/script.py` to get them to throw errors when tabs and spaces are mixed. Sorry I can't point you to a hard solution though :-(. Check out the indentation section of the PEP8 spec for more info: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#indentation

Comment: If line 447 (which isn't shown here) is an `if:` statement (or a loop, or a `with` statement, etc.), then it is perfectly acceptable for line 448 to be more indented than line 449.

Comment: @JohnGordon The if statement is line #445. #446 and #447 are fetching the data/rows from a sqlite cursor (same indentation as #448).

Comment: @hjpotter92 I was being too specific.  I should have said "if _any line_ prior to 448 is an `if` statement then the given indentation is acceptable, because the indented lines will be treated as part of the `if`, and line 449 will not be.

Comment: @JohnGordon I understood that. But since this entire snippet is part of a larger function->while->if->for->for blocks/nesting, the output should not be the same when code from #450 is reached, as that breaks out of at least 2 level of indent in #449 already, and diving back to level 5 should throw an error.

Comment: @hjpotter92 The syntax is correct.  If you're objecting on the basis of test output, then your tests must be wrong.